# Flutter run Error : Gradle could not start your build

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a window10 user, and it's an error that came out after running the project in android studio.
There was no particular error when I checked with 'flutter doctor' at the window terminal.
The code below is an error output from the terminal.

```bash
Resolving dependencies...
Got dependencies!
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Cannot create service of type BuildSessionActionExecutor using method LauncherServices$ToolingBuildSessionScopeServices.createActionExecutor() as there is a problem with parameter #21 of type FileSystemWatchingInformation.
   > Cannot create service of type BuildLifecycleAwareVirtualFileSystem using method VirtualFileSystemServices$GradleUserHomeServices.createVirtualFileSystem() as there is a problem with parameter #7 of type GlobalCacheLocations.
      > Cannot create service of type GlobalCacheLocations using method GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createGlobalCacheLocations() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<GlobalCache>.
         > Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
            > Timeout waiting to lock journal cache (C:\Users\SJMoon\.gradle\caches\journal-1). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
              Owner PID: 18476
              Our PID: 1472
              Owner Operation: 
              Our operation: 
              Lock file: C:\Users\SJMoon\.gradle\caches\journal-1\journal-1.lock

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I updated the Android studio and sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Exit Android Studio
2. Kill all Gradle processes
3. Delete C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\journal-1\journal-1.lock
4. Try again